# How can i show my main WPF window after successful login?

Tags: c#, wpf, authentication

I started learning WPF recently and I am trying to write a simple login system.

I got it to "work", it is verifing if the credentials are correct according to the database i made and returning successful, but i couldn't make it open the main window after the login.

Can anyone help?

This is the login click event

```
private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        if(VerifyUser(textBoxUser.Text, textBoxPassword.Password))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login Succeded", "Login", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            this.Close();
            
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User or Password invalid", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }
```

And this is the verify user code

```
private bool VerifyUser(string username, string password)
    {
        con.Open();
        com.Connection = con;
        com.CommandText = "select Usuario_Cod from tblUsuario where Usuario_Nome='"+username+"' and Usuario_Senha='"+password+"'";
        dr = com.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            if(Convert.ToBoolean(dr["Usuario_Cod"]) == true)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

My exact problem is that i don't know what kind of code i have to add to make it show my main window after the login window is closed in case of success

Example: user should only get access to the main window if he provides a valid username and password

[Login Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRsdr.png) and [Main Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36vZM.png)

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: i edited it, first time asking a question, sorry

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection! Take a look at OWASP and its article on sql injection for more information. You should use parametrized queries to prevent this

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work adding the following:

```
private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        if(VerifyUser(textBoxUser.Text, textBoxPassword.Password))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login Succeded", "Login", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            Sistema sistema = new Sistema();
            sistema.Show();
            this.Close();
            
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User or Password invalid", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }
```